# Why GNU make removes intermediate targets when using pattern rules?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile like the following:

```
.PHONY: all
all: foo_1.txt foo_2.txt foo_xxx.txt

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -f foo_* bar_*

foo_%.txt: bar_%.txt
        cp $< $@

#.PRECIOUS: bar_%.txt
bar_%.txt:
        touch $@ 

bar_2.txt:
        touch $@
```

The output of "make all" is folowing

```
touch bar_1.txt 
cp bar_1.txt foo_1.txt
touch bar_2.txt
cp bar_2.txt foo_2.txt
touch bar_xxx.txt 
cp bar_xxx.txt foo_xxx.txt
rm bar_xxx.txt bar_1.txt
```

The intermediate files created by the rule using pattern (bar_xxx.txt, bar_1.txt) are removed on the end. I have found that this behaviour can be supressed by .PRECIOUS (in the code is the line intentionally commented out).

Why are intermediate files created by rule with pattern removed by default and files created by rule without pattern are not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the definition of "intermediate files", you can't have an intermediate file created by an explicit rule (a rule "without a pattern").

See the section on [Chains of Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html) to understand this feature.  If you have specific questions then please update your question.